# Adding a column to pandas.DataFrame with randomly assigned values from a given set

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset like:

```
df["movie"] 
A
B
C
D
```

How to add another columns["genre"] with randomly assigned values from given list?

```
genres = ["action", "drama", "comedy"]
```

so that my `df` would look like：

```
movies genre
  A    action
  B    drama
  C    drama
  D    comedy
    ...
```

i've tried:

```
def addGenreColumn():
   for line in data:
       data["genre"] = random.choice(['action', 'comedy', 'drama'])
addGenreColumn()
```

but it will assign only one value from the list, like all `'action'`s or all `'comedy'`s. What is the proper way of dealing with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with a list comprehension iterating over movies:

```
import random
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'movie':['A','B','C','D']})

def addGenre():
    data["genre"] = [random.choice(['action', 'comedy', 'drama']) for movie in data.movie]
    
addGenre()

print(data)
```

Output:

```
  movie   genre
0     A   drama
1     B  action
2     C  comedy
3     D  action
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `numpy.random.choice` like:

```
data["genre"] = numpy.random.choice(genres, data["movie"].shape)
```

This will generate out of `genres` list with the shape as your first column so it can be assigned to the new column.